# Cassandra Spark : how to compare elements of two tables?

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two Cassandra tables created with Spark.

Now I need to compare these two tables.

Here are my tables

```
Table A

Cols:

Name LastName Adress City


Table B

Cols 

Adress City PostCode
```

Adress are not always the same : Street can be Strt, Str, St...

What I want to do. Check the adress of every rows of table A and compare them with every adress of table B. If they are almost the same I'll add the postcode to table A.

What is the best way to do. I have started with Solr Query but it seems quite slow. Now I'm trying to use Spark join but I'm not sure I can manage operations of columns that aren't exactly equals.

What do you think is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `join` is definitely the right way to go :) But in order to use join you would have to "harmonise" your `Address` columns, so that all addresses are formatted in the same way and "str", "st" and "street" are translated into a single unified word. You can do that with a UDF:

With UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val harmonise = udf((address: String) => ... //code that harmonises addresses)

tableA
  .select('Name, LastName, harmonise('Address) as "TableA_Address", 'City) 
  .join(tableB.select(harmonise('Address) as "TableB_Address", 'City, 'PostCode, 'TableA_Address === 'TableB_Address)
```

You could also do it with a `map`-function, but it's a little more cumbersome ;)

Oh, and as a final note - `joins` require shuffling, so they will tend to run much slower than trivial transformations like `map` or `filter`.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, bit it take hours. My tables are 10 and 30 millions. Do you think there is a way to optimize it even more ?

Comment: Well, how large is your cluster? How many executors, how many cores per executor and how much memory